# Using assembly object files from a subdirectory

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I have a small project with several .c files and one .s assembly file (crt0.s). The .c files are compiled into .o files, and are stored in the ./build subdirectory. These files compile and link correctly.

I would like the .s file to be stored in the ./build directory as well. So far, my makefile compiles the .s file and stores it in the correct location, however the linker can't find it.

The error I get is "ld.exe cannot find crt0.o". crt0.o is definitely being created in the ./build directory.

Here is the makefile:

```
CC=arm-none-eabi-gcc
AS=arm-none-eabi-as

CFLAGS=-nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -fno-builtin -Wall -T linker.ld -I./Include

objects=$(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,crt0.o main.o gpiopins.o framebuffer.o drawchar.o putchar.o intconv.o strlen.o kprintf.o kputchar.o)

OBJDIR=./build

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.s
    $(AS) -o $@ $< 

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

kernel.img: $(objects)
    $(CC) -o kernel.img $(objects) $(CFLAGS)

.PHONY : clean
clean:
    rm -f kernel.img
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f $(OBJDIR)/*.o
```

Any Ideas where I may be going wrong?

Thank you

---

EDIT:
If I do it manually, it is fine. eg:

```
kernel.img: $(objects)
    arm-none-eabi-as -o crt0.o crt0.s
    $(CC) -o kernel.img $(objects) $(CFLAGS)
```

However, this means that crt0.o is not in the ./build directory

Comment: Run make -n to see what's actually going on.

Comment: When your Makefile is executing, it should echo the commands it's running (by default).  Therefore, you can see exactly what commands you have asked for, and compare it what you've invoked manually.

Answer (score 0):

How can the "manual" variant be ok?  The var objects contains ./build/crt0.o which is what your linker needs.  The as command you pushed in is not providing it, so how does it help?  And even if it did, it would come too late, because all objects together are dependencies of the rule.

Do make clean and show us the output, that might help to spot what's going on.